# Angular model data from parent Controller

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have an controller, in template of it I pass data to child:

```
    <app-lexema-item [lexema]="lexema"></app-lexema-item>
```

the child controller is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lexema-item',
  templateUrl: './lexema-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lexema-item.component.css']
})
export class LexemaItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() lexema: Lexema;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and template for it:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <p>
        <br/> {{ lexema.name }} ({{ lexema.type }})
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Data passed correctly and injected into the child controller.

### Question

On next step I try add input for `lexema-item.component.html`:

```
    <input type="text" ngModel name="lexema.name">
```

but it doesn't work. I know that issue is in using `lexema.name` in name field but I do not know how to handle it (I tried alternative different cases `name=[(lexema.name)]`, `name="[(lexema.name)]"`) but unsuccessfully.

Is there any cool elegant solution?

Comment: Have you some errors in console?

Comment: no errors in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `name=[(lexema.name)]`. Hint: If you get undefined erros in console, hange `[(ngModel)]="lexema.name"` to `[(ngModel)]="lexema?.name"`.

Change this:

```
 <input type="text" ngModel name="lexema.name">
```

to this:

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lexema.name" name="name">
```

By using `[(ngModel)]` you must use `name`-attribute, beacuse it's important for template driven forms. Also you should import `FormsModule` into your app.module.ts.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

For more information read the official angular docs about [template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms).

Comment: `Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <p>
          <input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="lexema.name" name="name">`

Comment: import FormsModule into app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

First you will get an error of undefined element, because input binding will go after the markup is initialized. So for first we need to make sure that our element will be visible if the input is assigned.

If you want to bind to the `name` property.

```
<input type="text" ngModel name="{{ lexema?.name }}">
```

If you want to bind to the value of the `input`, you need to use `ngModel` with *two-way binding*.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lexema?.name">
```

Comment: `ngModel name="{{ lexema?.name }}"` - compiled but doesn't work. `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lexema?.name">` has an compilation error (`Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 14 in [lexema?.name=$event] in ng:///AppModule/LexemaItemComponent.html@4:29 ("
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <p>
          <input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="lexema?.name" name="name">`)

Comment: Change it with `<input *ngIf="lexema" type="text" [(ngModel)]="lexema.name">`

Comment: `Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <p>
          <input *ngIf="lexema" type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="lexema.name">
          <br/>...`

Comment: import FormsModule in the module